# Logic error adding 2 variables together in Unity Engine

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, variables, debugging, math

This sounds dumb, but I can't get 2 simple variables to add to each other, I have set points to add to 100 in the inspector. Everything would seem to work fine but when I all AddPoints from another script I Always get a debug log of 5. No matter what I set pointsToAdd to it always comes out as 5. I've tried score++; and that comes out just fine, I also tried to write a Debug.log just to make sure pointsToAdd wasn't set to something weird and it always returned 0! I don't know what in the world is happening. I must have screwed something up somehow.

```
private float score = 0;
public float pointsToAdd; // Setting in the editor

public void AddPoints()
{
    score += pointsToAdd; 
    Debug.Log(score);
}
```

And the script that's calling AddPoints contains:

```
public LevelManager levelManager; // I'm setting in the editor
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D other)
    {
        if (other.transform.CompareTag("Wall"))
        {
            levelManager.AddPoints();
        }
```

Edit: I've been testing for a few days now, with every chance I get completely unpredictable results until I set my score and Text UI to static variables, what about static variables changes the way that works?

Comment: you need to create a [MCVE] you snippet of code looks fine, apart from uninitialized `pointsToAdd`

Comment: @bolov I will try but there isn't much more than this, what would you like to see?

Comment: the minimum code that can **reproduce** the described behavior. If we put this code and test it ourselves we can't reproduce the result you get, so how can we help you? Create a **reproducible** example, a.k.a [mcve]

Comment: @bolov The other script contains the following:

public LevelManager levelManager;

if (other.transform.CompareTag("Wall"))
        {
            levelManager.AddPoints(100f);
        }

I don't know what else to add, what else would you like to see?

Comment: please [edit] your question to include the new information. All relevant information should go into the question itself. Comments are for requesting clarifications only.

Comment: @bolov Done, anything else?

Comment: your declared method takes no parameters, yet you are calling it with a float parameter. What you posted is not the code you have, or it would not compile.

Comment: @bolov I'm sorry, The other script has been updated to changes that have been made based on request by someone else to see if I can fix the problem, let me fix that.

Comment: you don't show where you set `pointsToAdd`. Create a [mcve]. Create a new project where you use only that mcve. Does your project compile? Does it exhibit the same faulty behavior? If yes post that mcve. Else tweak the mcve until you have a proper mcve and post that.

Comment: I set pointToAdd in the editor

Answer (score 0):

Going to need a little more information on this one.

However I don't know how you are doing it in the other script, I am assuming its not this script causing the problem, most likely the other. I would personally do:

OtherScript:

```
 pS.AddPoints(100f);
```

PointsScript

```
private float score; 

public void AddPoints(float pointsToAdd)
{
score += pointsToAdd;

}
```

Comment: After trying that script, score is no longer 5 but instead just remains at 0, all the other script has though is it has a variable to reference this script (That contains the code seen above) and it has this:

if (other.transform.CompareTag("Wall"))
        {           
          levelManager.AddPoints(100f);
        }

Comment: We are going to need both scripts. I don't think there is enough information.

Comment: What are the chances Unity has a bug? I've been putting debug logs all over the place testing things and all the sudden things started working, now the problem seems to be that even though I have 

score = 0;
Debug.Log(score);

In my start function, the first debug log says score is 0, and then the debug logs after "score += pointsToAdd" continue to add onto the variable even after the game has been closed and reopened.

Comment: Possibly restart unity and your computer. My Unity has bugged before and that fixed it for me. New found errors popped up after restart. Make sure to save :)

Comment: Ok, That's fixed all traces of problems adding variables together, now the only problem is that the line that says score = 0; in start function does not appear to be working at all, I ran some tests and found everything works fine if I put score = 0; on the other script but I need this script to act as the manager so I can't do that long term.